# UIView items don't appear in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, uiview, ios-simulator, uitableview, uistoryboard

Have created a LocationDetailsViewController (subclass of UITableViewController) and have done some layout work in Storyboard. This class is part of another Navigation Controller, which has two bar buttons: Cancel and Tag!

My problem is that when I run the program, none of the layout items which are part of LocationDetailsViewController appear in the view. The title and bar buttons appear fine; but nothing which is part of LocationDetailsViewController appear.

Any idea why?

Comment: Is it a dynamic or static table? have you set up your delegate and datasource correctly?

Comment: The cells are static. Haven't written the methods and delegate methods yet, just want to check my design. Funny thing is that nothing appears in iOS Simulator.

Comment: When you say the class is "part of another Navigation View Controller", you mean it is embedded in a navigation controller in the storyboard?

Comment: Yes it is embedded in the NavController